# Is there a term to refer to languages where variables are not preassigned a type?

Tags: types, programming-languages

For example JS, Python, Ruby, Smalltalk, etc. In those languages, the only place where the type of a variable is written in code is at instantiation time.
I was thinking in the term 'loosely typed languages', but found it a bit, well, loose. References to papers that define nomenclature for this is also welcome.

Comment: [Dynamically typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#DYNAMIC)?

Comment: But look at Java, which does not fit in the category I described. Isn't Java a dynamically typed language? While it is type-checked statically, it also does dynamic dispatch as default.

Comment: Let me get this straight real quick... You are looking for a term which describes creating variables without specifying a type and where checking for correctness only happens at runtime. This clearly is dynamic typing because Java would bomb you with errors. Dynamic dispatching is needed, because of polymorphism and has little to do with dynamic typing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually called "Duck Typing". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing .

Comment: Nice try! But in fact, I think Haskell (I forgot most of it many many years ago) also supports duck typing. But your response also helped me find my way to the answer which was were else than the wiki.c2.com. The name I was looking for is "implicit typing", and it comes in different flavors, as explained in http://wiki.c2.com/?ImplicitTyping. There is also a nice page for Duck Typing there!

Comment: Then you should upvote it right? Besides, if "nice try" means "not quite correct", please say why.

Answer (score 0):

Languages that do not require type declaration (manifest typing) for variables are called [Dynamically Typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_type_checking). The variables "acquire" type at run-time and it is the type of the object that is assigned to them. The variables can change their type every time a new object is assigned to them.

I reserve Duck Typing to refer to Object Type System only: it allows for "cheaper" implementation of what would normally we achieved with use of formal interfaces.